# PHP one instance returns an object with #5

Tags: php, object, singleton, instances

What i have learned about objects in php is that the hash with a number (#n) points to the instantiation times for example :

if we have something like this `object(Index)#5 (1)` means that we have 5 instances of the `Index` object.

However in my case i'm working on a custom PHP MVC i have only instantiated the class once (i'm sure only once. a model class directly within the controller ) but i'm getting an object like so

```
object(Timino\App\Models\Index)#5 (1)
```

so why is this happening ?

do namespaces affect this ! ?

does this have an affection to the performance ?!

Comment: For my understanding: #n is number of all objects instantiated while your script runs. It means this object is the fifth instance of any class in your scripts.

Comment: @BenRoob i'm instantiating other classes like database and helpers and i'm getting different hashes  #4 #7  if like you said i should get an ascending nomber !!

Comment: Then other objects will be instantiaed between #4 and #7. E.g. if a DB class has inner objects, or as you mentioned instances of helpers.

Comment: ok i will try to dump them all in an organized way and see

Comment: update: tried to "more answer" your further questions ;)

Comment: You are right dude the hash is an identifier of the object and not the number of instances thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces should not affect this. For performance issues, the number of objects during script runtime will only have an impact, if the script is getting close or over the max memory limit. FYI, here are some [considerations about performance](http://php.net/manual/de/features.gc.performance-considerations.php).

A simple example to show/explain the "object counter":

```
class TestClass {
    public $number = 2;
}

class ClassInner {
    protected $number = 5;
    protected $innerObject;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->innerObject = new \stdClass();
    }
}


$testInstance = new TestClass();
$classInner = new ClassInner();

$classInner2 = new ClassInner();
$testInstance2 = new TestClass();

$classInner3 = $classInner2;

echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($testInstance);
var_dump($classInner);

var_dump($classInner2);
var_dump($testInstance2);
var_dump($classInner3);

echo '</pre>';
```

Should result in this output. Pleas have a look at the order of instances and count:

```
object(TestClass)#1 (1) {
  ["number"]=>
  int(2)
}
object(ClassInner)#2 (2) {
  ["number":protected]=>
  int(5)
  ["innerObject":protected]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (0) {
  }
}
object(ClassInner)#4 (2) {
  ["number":protected]=>
  int(5)
  ["innerObject":protected]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
  }
}
object(TestClass)#6 (1) {
  ["number"]=>
  int(2)
}
object(ClassInner)#4 (2) {
  ["number":protected]=>
  int(5)
  ["innerObject":protected]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```